# Compare columns and put the output in additional column

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's start with the example of the data:

```
structure(list(P1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Apple", 
"Grape", "Orange", "Peach", "Tomato"), class = "factor"), P2 = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Banana", "Cucumber", "Lemon", "Orange", 
"Potato", "Tomato"), class = "factor"), P1_location_subacon = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Fridge", "Table"), class = "factor"), 
    P1_location_all_predictors = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("Table,Desk,Bag,Fridge,Bed,Shelf,Chair", 
    "Table,Shelf,Cupboard,Bed,Fridge", "Table,Shelf,Fridge"), class = "factor"), 
    P2_location_subacon = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Fridge", 
    "Shelf"), class = "factor"), P2_location_all_predictors = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Shelf,Fridge", "Shelf,Fridge,Bed", 
    "Table,Shelf,Fridge"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("P1", 
"P2", "P1_location_subacon", "P1_location_all_predictors", "P2_location_subacon", 
"P2_location_all_predictors"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I would like to compare the two pairs of column. First pair which I would like to comapre is `P1_location_subacon` with `P2_location_subacon`. The second pair is `P1_location_all_predictors` with `P2_location_all_predictors`.

How I want to compare them ? In each column you have different "locations" of the fruit/vegetable. So:

1. if the location is the same in the first pair (P1/2_location_subacon) I would like to put number `2` in the additional column.
2. if the location is the same in the second pair (P1/2_location_all_predictors) I would like to put number `1` in the additional column. That one is a bit more complicated because not all of the locations have to be the same. At least one of them has to be the same for both fruits/vegetables.
3. if in both cases they are different put `0`. You won't see such situation in the example data.

To summarize I show you the output which I would like to achieve:

```
structure(list(P1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Apple", 
"Grape", "Orange", "Peach", "Tomato"), class = "factor"), P2 = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Banana", "Cucumber", "Lemon", "Orange", 
"Potato", "Tomato"), class = "factor"), P1_location_subacon = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Fridge", "Table"), class = "factor"), 
    P1_location_all_predictors = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("Table,Desk,Bag,Fridge,Bed,Shelf,Chair", 
    "Table,Shelf,Cupboard,Bed,Fridge", "Table,Shelf,Fridge"), class = "factor"), 
    P2_location_subacon = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Fridge", 
    "Shelf"), class = "factor"), P2_location_all_predictors = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Shelf,Fridge", "Shelf,Fridge,Bed", 
    "Table,Shelf,Fridge"), class = "factor"), X = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Correct = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("P1", 
"P2", "P1_location_subacon", "P1_location_all_predictors", "P2_location_subacon", 
"P2_location_all_predictors", "X", "Correct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: As stated in my answer, the reason for the slowness is relying on a loop for the grep function as it is not vectorized. For anyone who is looking to help answer, I think the solution will be to replace those two lines. That said, the requirement is fairly computationally intensive

Comment: my answer should be much much quicker now.

Comment: Your desired output contains an `X` column with all blanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: using feedback from here [Test two columns of strings for match row-wise in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854434/test-two-columns-of-strings-for-match-row-wise-in-r) I have improved my answer.

Where DT is your table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT <- data.table(sapply(DT,as.character))

DT[, P1_location_all_predictors := gsub(",","|",P1_location_all_predictors)]
DT[, P1_location_subacon := gsub(",","|",P1_location_subacon)]

DT[, match_all_pred := grepl(P1_location_all_predictors, P2_location_all_predictors) + 0, by = P1_location_all_predictors]
DT[, match_subacon := grepl(P1_location_subacon, P2_location_subacon), by = P1_location_subacon]


DT[, P1_location_all_predictors := gsub("\\|",",",P1_location_all_predictors)]
DT[, P1_location_subacon := gsub("\\|",",",P1_location_subacon)]
```

I instead opted for two columns vs your `0/1/2` notation; it makes the code less straightforward as you have to rely on nested ifs. I also think that multiple columns is better as you can clearly see the `F/F`, `T/F`, `F/T`, and `T/T` cases.

If you must create the `0/1/2`, you can call

```
DT[, MyCol := match_all_pred - match_subacon*match_all_pred+match_subacon*2]
```

which assumes that subacon supersedes the all location.

Comment: It looks like it's working for the example data but doesn't want to work for my main data... I have no idea why yet. Is it necessary to put the comas between all the letters in one of the column. Can it be removed later ?

Comment: That's the error which I get when I try the code on my main data: `Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  RHS of assignment to existing column 'MyCol' is zero length but not NULL. If you intend to delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; e.g., NA_integer_. If you are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, as with all column type changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in the new column.
`

Comment: @ShaxiLiver, I made a couple of silly mistakes in my code, including how it was returned (which flagged the error) and how I changed back the `|`s to `,`s. Edited now.

Comment: That works perfectly fine! I just have one more question. To make my data more reliable. I've already found out that in few cases (like in 50 rows out of 10k) I have instead of 1 possible localization for  `P1/2_location_subacon` two or three. As I said I can leave it like that but I have to skip those 50 rows. Maybe you still have some time and you would like to write a code to include such situation. It is mostly about this code `DT[P1_location_subacon == P2_location_subacon, MyCol := 2]`. Those other locations are separated by comma.... Thx !!

Comment: Multiple columns is costly relative to taking advantage of sub-assignment, like `DT[cond_for_2,MyCol:=2]; DT[!cond_for_2,MyCol:=cond_for_1]`. This way, you don't have to compute the `cond_for_1` for every row. Anyway, I might still go with two columns as you do here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
myData <- data.frame(sapply(myData, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

doesIntersect <- function(setA, setB) {length(intersect(setA,setB)) > 0}

myData$Correct <- 0
﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿myData$Correct[mapply(doesIntersect, strsplit(myData$P1_location_all_predictors, ","), strsplit(myData$P2_location_all_predictors, ","))] <- 1
myData$Correct[mapply(setequal, strsplit(myData$P1_location_subacon, ","), strsplit(myData$P2_location_subacon, ","))] <- 2

> myData$Correct
[1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```