# Test two columns of strings for match row-wise in R

Tags: regex, r, data.table

Let's say I have two columns of strings:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = c("a","aa","bb"), y = c("b","a","bbb"))
```

For each row, I want to know whether the string in x is present in column y. A looping approach would be:

```
for (i in 1:length(DT$x)){
  DT$test[i] <- DT[i,grepl(x,y) + 0]
}

DT
    x   y test
1:  a   b    0
2: aa   a    0
3: bb bbb    1
```

Is there a vectorized implementation of this? Using `grep(DT$x,DT$y)` only uses the first element of x.

Comment: @LegalizeIt yes, I'm not looking for situations where a == b, but where you have partial string matches across rows. The above tests if x is in y, but you can re-run the other way if that is important. I'm not sure what you mean by "Why isn't "a" in column y?"

Comment: @DavidArenburg good thought, but only works for when x is unique. I have tried `DT[, test := grepl(x, y) + 0, by = .I]` but get the same `argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` error. That said, there might be a munging solution where you first call DT[, RowI := .I], then use `by = rowI`

Comment: It's not only working when `x` is unique. Works perfectly fine for `DT <- data.table(x = c("a","aa","aa","bb"), y = c("b","a","a", "bbb"))`, for example.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right... it will pass the same argument to grepl for each group of x, which is all the same input. Clever. I am benchmarking all the answers and will respond with the best one.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there. You asked this for the bounty question...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, but having already answered the bounty question, and getting frustrated at getting over the vectorization problem of grepl. Tried to reword the core issue of it here in hopes that it could be used to answer the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply do

```
DT[, test := grepl(x, y), by = x]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `mapply` (`Vectorize` is really just a wrapper for `mapply`)

```
DT$test <- mapply(grepl, pattern=DT$x, x=DT$y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your responses. I've benchmarked them all, and come up with the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

DT <- data.table(x = rep(c("a","aa","bb"),1000), y = rep(c("b","a","bbb"),1000))

DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)
DT4 <- copy(DT)

microbenchmark(
DT1[, test := grepl(x, y), by = x]
,
DT2$test <- apply(DT, 1, function(x) grepl(x[1], x[2]))
,
DT3$test <- mapply(grepl, pattern=DT3$x, x=DT3$y)
,
{vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl)
DT4[, test := as.integer(vgrepl(x, y))]}
)
```

Results

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                               expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
                                             DT1[, `:=`(test, grepl(x, y)), by = x]   758.339   908.106   982.1417   959.6115  1035.446   1883.872   100
                            DT2$test <- apply(DT, 1, function(x) grepl(x[1], x[2])) 16840.818 18032.683 18994.0858 18723.7410 19578.060  23730.106   100
                              DT3$test <- mapply(grepl, pattern = DT3$x, x = DT3$y) 14339.632 15068.320 16907.0582 15460.6040 15892.040 117110.286   100
 {     vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl)     DT4[, `:=`(test, as.integer(vgrepl(x, y)))] } 14282.233 15170.003 16247.6799 15544.4205 16306.560  26648.284   100
```

Along with being the most syntactically simple, the data.table solution is also the fastest.

Comment: I'm not sure what the etiquette here is (to accept David's answer or mine). Regardless, +1s for all for showing the number of ways this can be done.

Comment: For this particular example (with both `x` and `y` values repeating), I see a slight improvement with `by=.(x,y)` in place of `by=x` on the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `grepl` function into an apply function to operate on each row of your data table where the first column contains the string to search for and the second column contains the string to search in. This should give you a vectorized solution to your problem.

```
> DT$test <- apply(DT, 1, function(x) as.integer(grepl(x[1], x[2])))
> DT
    x   y test
1:  a   b    0
2: aa   a    0
3: bb bbb    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vectorize`:

```
vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl)
DT[, test := as.integer(vgrepl(x, y))]
DT
    x   y test
1:  a   b    0
2: aa   a    0
3: bb bbb    1
```