# grepl functionality in vectorial conditional statement

Tags: r

How may I obtain the same functionality as `grepl` within a vectorial conditional statement?

I wish to transform raw data of geographical divisions (mixed with other categories) by prepending the city name where it is missing from district names:

```
#Build index dataframe
(index <- data.frame(div_raw=c("Brussels", "Paris", "Paris I", "II", "total"), 
                     city=c("Brussels", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", NA)))
#   div_raw     city
#1 Brussels Brussels
#2    Paris    Paris
#3  Paris I    Paris
#4       II    Paris
#5    total     <NA>

#Prepend city name to district names, where available
index$div <- with(index, paste(ifelse(div_raw != city & !is.na(city), city, ""), div_raw))
index
#   div_raw     city           div
#1 Brussels Brussels      Brussels
#2    Paris    Paris         Paris
#3  Paris I    Paris Paris Paris I
#4       II    Paris      Paris II
#5    total     <NA>         total
```

As can be seen, we should also test for whether the city is already included in the district name, but `grepl` applies the entire pattern vector rather than just the matching pattern value:

```
index$div <- with(index, paste(ifelse(div_raw != city & !is.na(city) & !grepl(city, div_raw), city, ""), div_raw))
#Warning message:
#In grepl(city, div_raw) :
#  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

index
#   div_raw     city           div
#1 Brussels Brussels      Brussels
#2    Paris    Paris         Paris
#3  Paris I    Paris Paris Paris I
#4       II    Paris      Paris II
#5    total     <NA>         total
```

The expected result:

```
index
#   div_raw     city           div
#1 Brussels Brussels      Brussels
#2    Paris    Paris         Paris
#3  Paris I    Paris       Paris I
#4       II    Paris      Paris II
#5    total     <NA>         total
```

Comment: A very similar question had already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30854650/7114709), although I was only able to find it thanks to the `vgrepl` keyword from @PKumar's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this using `Vectorize`, It should work, instead of grepl use `vgrepl` like below. Vectorize function vectorizes on the parameters, although you can choose what parameters to vectorize upon using `vectorize.args`, since by default grepl is not vectorized on patterns with input you are getting this error:

```
vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl)
# you can write this also: vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = c('x', 'pattern'))

index$div <- with(index, paste(ifelse(div_raw != city & !is.na(city) & !vgrepl(city, div_raw), city, ""), div_raw))
```

**Output**:

```
> index
   div_raw     city       div
1 Brussels Brussels  Brussels
2    Paris    Paris     Paris
3  Paris I    Paris   Paris I
4       II    Paris  Paris II
5    total     <NA>     total
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use vectorized `grepl` i.e `stringr::str_detect` :

```
index$div <- with(index, paste(ifelse(div_raw != city & !is.na(city) & 
                 !stringr::str_detect(div_raw, city), city, ""), div_raw))
index

#   div_raw     city       div
#1 Brussels Brussels  Brussels
#2    Paris    Paris     Paris
#3  Paris I    Paris   Paris I
#4       II    Paris  Paris II
#5    total     <NA>     total
```